# Sbt tasks with additional commands

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

In addition to my main Play app, I have webpack npm task to build my javascripts.

Is it possible to hook the sbt tasks so that it can run arbitrary unix command?

For example, when I run `sbt run`, I also want to invoke `npm run watch`, and

when I run `sbt stage`, I also want to invoke `npm run build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Modifying an Existing Task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Modifying+an+Existing+Task) section in the SBT docs on how to do that.